# Rails Foreigner Plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, foreigner

My user table should have a role_id ( not added in my table yet )
My role table has uses the default primary id: id

I am currently trying to use the foreigner plugin where it looks like ...

```
class AddForeignKeyToUserFromRole < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_foreign_key( :users,:roles )
  end
end
```

But my error is saying the following:
Mysql2::Error: Key column 'role_id' doesn't exist in table: ALTER TABLE `users` ADD CONSTRAINT `users_role_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`role_id`) REFERENCES `roles`(id)

What is going on?? What I'm I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`role_id`, just like it says, and like you said?

How can you set a foreign key on a table column when the table column doesn't exist?

Comment: I must be really out of it... haha. Thanks for the input.